# Login user with MS Teams bot

Tags: botframework, botconnector

I'm working on a bot using the MS Botframework and trying to use a signin card with MS Teams. I can get the signin card to show up in Teams as expected, but clicking the sign in button doesn't do anything.

Any ideas what is going on here? I can't find much documentation about how to sign in a user for a session with the bot.

I'm using the Nodejs botbuilder library.

My code:

```
bot.dialog('/signin', [
    function (session) { 
        var msg = new builder.Message(session)
            .attachments([
                new builder.SigninCard(session)
                    .text('You need to sign in to Bonusly to continue')
                    .button('Sign In', 'https://myapp.com/users/sign_in_start')
            ]);
        session.endDialog(msg);
    }
]);
```

Comment: Just gonna leave this here for future reference: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2104

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue.  I don't think its related to NodeJS as i'm programming in C#

Answer (score 0):

Currently MS Teams supports Sign-In cards but only if the action for the button is specified as 'open url' [as stated in this Microsoft document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/botsmessages#cards). It's probably failing because you specified the button action to be 'Sign In' in your line:

`.button('Sign In', 'https://myapp.com/users/sign_in_start')`

Also check out this [github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2104) that talks further about this.